# 1D ising system: reducing configuration with respecet to symmetry and total magnetization

Tags: ising-model

this question is mathematical in its sense and considers the following 1D ising spin model

$$s_1s_2s_3....s_{n-1}$$

where $s_i=\pm 1$.

I would like to find the total number of different configurations after reducing symmetry and 'total magnetization'

for example, for a system of $n=4$ the following terms are symmetric
$$(-1,+1,+1,+1),(+1,+1,+1,-1)$$

and the following terms have a the same total magnetization ($\sum s_i =2$)
$$(+1,-1,+1,+1),(-1,+1,+1,+1)$$

note that there are only two cases of $\sum s_i=2$ because of the symmetry

with these definitions, can I obtain an analytical expression for the total number of state as a function of $n$?

Comment: Which symmetries  do you consider?

Comment: Can you clarify which states you count together?